# React: Plain bootstrap wrapping cards-deck in a cards component

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

hey guys I'm trying to create with plain bootstrap a cards deck

In my main file have defined the deck:

```
<div className="container">
      <div className="card-deck">
        <MyCard />
        <MyCard />
        <MyCard />
      </div>
```

And this is my Card component:

```
<div>
  <div className="card mb-4">
    ...
  </div>
```

So I defined mb-4 to have 3 cards in one row. However, the cards display two each row. So I have two cards in one row and another column with the third card. How can I fix that?

Please don't recommend to use reactstrap or react-bootstrap. I don't prefer using plain bootstrap and write the components myself.

Comment: what are you want to ask? create your problem demo first!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The outer div of the card component was the problem.